# When I add a value to a cell in a selected column, I want it to coppy to another Google Sheet

Tags: javascript

Supposing, you have a list of data in a sheet1, now, you need to copy the rows which contain the text “Complete” in Column E to another new sheet2 and text “Not start” in Column E to another new sheet3,text “Prorees” in Column E to another new sheet4,text “Not Complete” in Column E to another new sheet5 
How could deal with this job in Google Apps Script?
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_O_L1W828Y7hyfwi57coYv5udnmiJ1MMc52GfpfrnE/edit#gid=1310628341

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you're going to need a combination of two methods:

1. Google Apps Script's [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) method, and the chainable methods [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).
2. Using the JavaScript [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

The `getRange()` method is used in your Google script to target specific cells, (for example, the columns you need to target in sheet1). When you then use the method `getValues()` (ex: `ss.getRange( ... ).getValues()`), you'll create an array with the data from the range you've targeted.

Once you have that array, you can then iterate over it using something like the `array.forEach()` method. For example, you might use the `array.push()` method to only push values into a new array when the cell next to it has the string "Complete" in it.

Once you have that new array, you can then use the `getRange( ... ).setValues()` methods to "print" to sheet2.